# addTableRow with a key and a subject in template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, html-lists

i need to make an table for school. But the table is a template and i don't know how to use it. The exercise is to make a function that can do this: "This function will add a row to the table using the template element of the homepage." The function is:

```
<template id="subject-template">
        <li class="subject">
            <span class="vakcode"></span>
            <span class="vaknaam"></span>
            <span class="studiejaar"></span>
            <span class="blok"></span>
            <span class="edit"></span>
            <span class="delete"></span>
        </li>
    </template>


function addTableRow(key, subject){
    var template = document.getElementById("subject-template")
    var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    var li = clone.querySelectorAll("li")
    li.textContent = key + subject
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how one might use a template element. This uses a list here rather than a table as that's what your example uses. Another example can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

```js
const template = document.getElementById("subject-template");
const list = document.getElementById("list");

function addTableRow(key, subject) {
  const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  
  clone.querySelector(".key").textContent = key;
  clone.querySelector(".subject").textContent = subject;
  
  list.appendChild(clone);
}

addTableRow('A', 'Clouds');
addTableRow('B', 'Rivers');
```

```html
<template id="subject-template">
  <li class="subject-item">
    <span class="key"></span>
    <span class="subject"></span>
  </li>
</template>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```